# Prove that there are only 2 solutions of $\frac{n+3}{n-1}=x$ for $n$ natural and $x$ natural.

Tags: number-theory

I know that the solutions are $1) n=3$ and  $2) n=5$ but I don't know how to prove that they are only the two.

Comment: $n+3 \geq 2(n-1) \Rightarrow 5 \geq n$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{n+3}{n-1} = 1 + \frac{4}{n-1}.$$

For that to be an integer, $n-1$ must be a divisor of $4$, so $n-1 \in \{1,2,4\}$, and $n \in \{2,3,5\}$. There are in fact three solutions.

Comment: dammit , i was going to post this answer . (+1)

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{n+3}{n-1}=1+{4\over{n-1}}$$
And $4\over{n-1}$ is natural only at n=2,3,5.

Answer (score 1):

Also, another way to proove it (I'm not sure it is too mathematical, but anyway):

If $n > 5$, then $$\frac{n+3}{n-1} < 2$$
 (this is easy to proove), so for $n > 5$ there is not natural $x$ (since $1 < x < 2$ on this interval)

$n = 4$ isn't solution.

$n = 2$ is not too.

For $n < 2$ the fraction will be either a negative number or $|n + 3| < |n - 1|$, so there can't be a solution with $n < 2$.

Sorry for bad indent, it is my first post here. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes its very good.